# Android Firebase and Converting Hashmap back to Object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I'm pulling out information into a series of classes using the Firebase SDK in Android. My classes do indeed contain my data, but on trying to extract my data of something as the same class, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to CustomItem
```

I have a class, called `CustomItems`, that has:

```
public Map<String, CustomItem> Items;
```

I'm loading this, by setting the following in the `onDataChange` event.

```
Items = (HashMap<String, CustomItem>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Anyhow, on trying to read this information by using `CustomItem item = Items.get('key')`, shows me the correct object name of CustomItem in Android Studio and it's Intellisense, however always returns a Hashmap.

Having written this so far, Im wondering if I now need to actually iterate through the children to set a new CustomItem as

```
item = child.getValue(CustomItem.class);
```

And then add that item to a List in CustomItems.

Comment: The other bit to this, if I figure that I actually do have a HashMap and insteaad try to do HashMap<String, CustomItem>  = Items.get('key'), then it throws a syntax error in that HashMap cannot be applied to CustomItem. The item is neither a HashMap, or a CustomItem. Intellisense thinks it's a CustomItem, but I get a Hashmap returned instead.

Comment: Cast to the simpler `Map` type: `Items = (Map<String, CustomItem>) dataSnapshot.getValue();`. But I'm not sure you can read all `CustomItem`s like that, or if you need to do them one by one.

Comment: This is weird. I can actually navigate all the information as a HashMap inside the debugger, but cannot enter say Item.get('key').subkey because it reports "No such instance field" even though I can navigate it. Confused. And still Intellisense thinks Im bringing back a CustomItem not a HashMap, but I navigate a HashMap instead. The Map didn't work either, same issues.

Comment: Please add your database structure.